# Trying to empty (but not delete) a sharepoint 2010 CMS

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sql-server

I have a SharePoint 2010 CMS that I need to empty but not delete, it was full of test data (approx. 1TB worth) but I now need to delete all the content and fill it with live data/documents.

All I can find in the sharepoint interface is an option to delete the whole CMS (which I would rather avoid)

A colleague tried to delete content through a windows explorer session but the database (sql2008R2) & the sharepoint still believe the data is still there even though I can browse the CMS & can se the content is no longer there.
I have tried to shrink the database in sql but that made no difference...

Is there a simple/straightforward way of clearing down the CMS or am I stuck with deleting it & building it again ?

Answer (score 0):

There is couple of ways you could do it.

1. If you go with the delete route you need to ensure that after deleting items from the libraries/lists you need to clear recycle bins. 
   But instead of doing it via explorer session use powershell here you have small [example:](http://sharepointjack.com/2013/delete-all-items-in-a-sharepoint-list-with-powershell/)

   $web = get-spweb https://url to your web
       $list = $web.lists | where {$_.title -eq "Name_of_your_list"}
       Write-host "List $($list.title) has $($list.items.count) entries"
       $items = $list.items
       foreach ($item in $items)
       {
           Write-host "  Say Goodbye to $($item.id)" -foregroundcolor red
           $list.getitembyid($Item.id).Delete()
       }
2. Second option would be to save the the site as template and create new site based on that template. (I assume that you have some customisation you want to preserve)

Comment: The saving as a template (without the CMS content) seems like a plan... it links to a custom web browser front-end that I don't want to risk losing the settings to (it took a while to get all working in the 1st place).

Answer (score 0):

The site collection recycle bin was enabled with the default 30 day retention causing complications (we didn't know there was one) but that's why the sql database hadn't cleared down.

If I delete all the docs/folder in the CMS explorer view and then remove this recycle bin then it will dump all the documents in it (or disable this 2nd recycle bin and then just delete the docs/folders) apparently.